# How to get all groups for a user in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api

Is there any way to get all groups for a user? My code which is not working properly is below;

```
  var pageToken = null;
  var filter= {userKey: "abc@gmail.com"}; //this is a member's email address
  do {
    var result = AdminDirectory.Groups.list(filter);
    filter.pageToken = result.pageToken;

    if(result.groups) {
      groups = groups.concat(result.groups.map(function(group) {
        return {
          name: group.name
        };
      }));
    }
  }
  while(result.pageToken);

  for(i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    console.log(groups[i].name);
  }
```

It returns empty groups array.

Comment: What part isnt working? the query? the concatenation? both?

Comment: Query does not work.

Comment: Then the user is not a direct member of any Google Groups. Consider testing your input on the API Explorer / "Try this API": https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list

Answer (score 0):

The code is simpler than that, no need to use token.
The returned value is an array of objects with several properties (see JSON)

It goes like this

```
function myFunction() {
  var user = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({userKey:"userEmail@xxx.yyy"});
  var groupMembership = [];
  var userGroupProperties = user.groups;
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(userGroupProperties));
  for(var n=0 ; n<userGroupProperties.length ; n++){
    groupMembership.push(userGroupProperties[n].name)
  }
  Logger.log('groupMembership = '+groupMembership);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it returns all the groups for a user. However, for some members I could not get their groups. When I checked the detailed response I see only etag and kind parameters, does that mean those members are inactive or suspended?

Comment: I'm not sure, check the API documentation... What do you see in the admin console for these users?

Comment: I thought, the users may be inactive or suspended and that is why I do not see their groups, but I could not find it in Google.admin.directory api documentation.

Comment: For these users I see only etag and kind parameters; {
  "kind": "admin#directory#groups",
  "etag": etag
} 
 For the others, I see their groups too, {
  "kind": "admin#directory#groups",
  "etag": etag,
  "groups": [
    groups Resource
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string
}

Comment: @AshleyCam, I know its an old thread but still wanted to share my observation. It seems that the script needs G Suite Admin Privileges to be able extract group details. I am 100% that these users are not inactive.